# Google Maps API requires refresh to work correctly

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have problem coding the google maps API for my personal website. The google maps doesn't work until I refresh the browsers. Below are the scripts for google maps.

```
            <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&v3"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo get_bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/js/mk.js"></script>         

        <script type="text/javascript"> 

        var geocoder;
        var map;
        function initialize() {
        geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
        var myOptions = {
          zoom: 13,
          center: latlng,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        }
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);
        }

        function codeAddress(address) {

        geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
            var marker = new MarkerWithLabel({

            position: results[0].geometry.location,
            map: map,
            labelContent: address,
            labelAnchor: new google.maps.Point(22, 0),
            labelClass: "labels", // the CSS class for the label
            labelStyle: {opacity: 1.0}

            });
            } else {
                //alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
              }
            });
          }

        initialize();

        codeAddress("<?php 

            global $post;
            $pid = $post->ID;

            $terms = wp_get_post_terms($pid,'ad_location');
            foreach($terms as $term)
            {
                echo $term->name." ";
            }

            $location = get_post_meta($pid, "Location", true);  
            echo $location;

         ?>");

        </script>
```

Did I missed anything for the scripts? I didn't add API on it, but the console said "You have included the Google Maps API multiple times on this page. This may cause unexpected errors."

Comment: Are you loading the `script` inside a loop? If not what does `mk.js'` do? By the way these parameters `sensor=false&v3` are not needed.

Comment: did you  check if any other plugin is calling the maps api? check  your code font and see it.

Answer (score 2):

You need to make sure the map variable is initialized before you pass it to markerOptions.

A bit of overzealous debugging showed me that on the times that the page fails, the map is still undefined.

`The $(document).ready()` will usually occur before body.onload, so either put a call to initialize() at the very top of your `$(document).ready(function() { ... });` or put the code for initialize in there.

Also, though not strictly necessary, you should consider encapsulating your map variable instead of using a global.

Comment: Thank you for your time Marcos. I will try to move the code up to see how it works.